# Check if same value exist in an array if not store into array

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I can't figure out the logic to how to check if a value exist in an array and if it doesn't store it.

I have a array with information and I'm trying to just get the first instance since some of the values repeats, for example username it will show up more than once but I only need the first username I don't need to store multiple values of the same username in an array.

Righh now I'm using pushing all the valuse into the array as so

```
   for ($i=0; $i<count($info); $i++) {
              array_push($users, $info[$i]->username);
   }
```

Comment: If it's small, iterate over the whole array every time searching for the value

Comment: Try using in_array() function. See the manual.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Loop through the array and check to see if the value exists. If not, add it.
2. Use [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check to see if the value exists. If not, add it.
3. Add the value to the array and then use [`array_unique()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to eliminate duplicate values.